# What can I do to make my new installation look vanilla?

Tags: themes, desktop-environments

I have changed distros quite a few times. Most of the time, the distro installer will install a few config files to make the distro look in a certain way . For example, Lubuntu will change a few LXDE config files. It will keep other config files untouched.

Sometimes, after installing a new distro, I notice that some elements will keep the previous distro's look.

I dislike this. I want to keep my config files, except for the ones that affect the way a distro looks. In other words, I want Ubuntu to look vanilla after installing.

What config files should I remove before installing Ubuntu to get this done?

Comment: You haven't provided release details; for example Lubuntu now uses LXQt and not LXDE, so its configuration is rather different for modern releases as compared to older legacy releases (though some of the openbox config is the same). That also highlights one difference in that desktop store files differently; LXQt is Qt based so will use Qt themes, LXDE used GTK2, most modern GTK based use GTK3 configs, so files are splattered around your $HOME (~/.config/, ~/.local/  ... etc)

Comment: Yes, that's right. IMO a nice answer would be a script that would remove these config files for 90% of DEs

Comment: Wouldn't "desktop environment" be more appropriate than "distro" in your question?

Comment: Also, "new installation" in the title and "before installing Ubuntu" in the body (last sentence) isn't clear at least to me.

Answer (score 2):

> What config files should I remove before installing Ubuntu to get this done?

That is going to be difficult to answer as that would require knowledge of all possible configuration files.

But ... how I  do  it..

1. / on a partition.
2. /home on a partition. I do not use this for myself ...
3. and /discworld for my personal data.

When I re-install (and I do that at least once every 6 months) I format / and /home and mount /discworld. Formatting /home kills any relation to any previous installed desktop.

In /discworld I keep an edited copy of `~/config/user-dirs.dirs` that I copy back and that holds the directories like Desktop, and Downloads on /discworld. That disk also holds my apache and mysql config files and my websites and databases. All I need is a symlink to the original directories.

Since I also have 1 and 2 on the same sdd and 3 on a large hdd a re-install takes a few minutes. During re-install I always activate my internet connection so I can use firefox to stay connected on-line and that makes my downtime almost equal to the time the reboots take and me typing in my password for my wifi. Add in a post install script to remove and add all the things I want tweaked and my system is up and running again within 20 minutes.

Comment: That's an interesting answer!